# Adding a receptacle to a wall with an insulation blanket on the wall

Tags: wiring

I have a newly built home with blanket insulation on the basement walls.  There are no studs as the blanket insulation is attached directly to the cement wall.

Is it possible to add receptacles to the wall over or through the blanket insulation or is my only option to build a wall or partial wall in front of the blanket insulation.

Comment: Is there a finish on this wall? What type of "blanket" insulation are we talking about here?  How thick is it, for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Anything less than 1-1/2 plus the sheetrock is about the shallowest you can do and meet code.

This will hold a receptacle and allow a nm cable routed down the wall but no room for splices in the receptacle box.

the 1-1/4” space then the nmb on the wall but trying to put this in after the fact it would be best to surface mount. As junction boxes at the ceiling would need to be accessible or each run a home run lots of wire.

Surface mount conduit can be done it may not look as nice as hidden but is more common in basement spaces and may be the only legal way depending on how thick the insulation board is.